# Ansible: set http_proxy via inventory

Tags: ansible, environment-variables, http-proxy, ansible-inventory

I have a group of servers together in a site, where some of the servers have access only to a management network and not to the Internet, so I need to configure http_proxy for them to be able to pull packages, etc.

Now, I have a top-level playbook which I apply to all of the servers together, and I'm looking for a way to set the environment/http_proxy setting only for those servers that need it. Is there a way to somehow set the environment using host/group_vars?

I tried overriding the `ansible_env` variable, but it doesn't work, I guess it's getting overwritten in the first playbook step (`gather_facts`).

Apart from duplicating the plays in the playbook, limiting them to the group, and setting the environment there, is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not to be possible, as inventory variables are specific to ansible, they are not environment variables.

If the servers needs to have `proxy_http` set put it directly on the server on any relevant file, like `/etc/environment` to be system-wide or in your user profile files. This way ansible should use this transparently.

Furthermore the official ansible [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html) suggest to use environment variable at task or play level.